# Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

I am new in Spring Application with maven. Running my project to create the database objects based on my classes created, I got the following error: `Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect]  as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]`

[image: screenshot]

I have added these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

`MySQL55Dialect` was deprecated and removed from hibernate-core in Hibernate 6.2

See [Removal of support for legacy database versions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#database-versions)

> This version introduces the concept of minimum supported database version for most of the database dialects that Hibernate supports. This implies that the legacy code for versions that are no longer supported by their vendors, has been removed from the hibernate-core module. It is, however, still available in the hibernate-community-dialects module, just under a different package, namely org.hibernate.community.dialect instead of org.hibernate.dialect. Note that this also includes version specific dialects like PostgreSQL81Dialect, MariaDB102Dialect etc.
>
> The minimum supported dialect versions are as follows:
>
> MySQL 5.7

which leaves you with 2 options:

- use `MySQLDialect`
- import `hibernate-community-dialects` and use `MySQL55Dialect`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fixed using: **dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect**